# show all completed fields sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have been able to show/hide sharepoint fields in a new form, however, is there a way of showing all fields in the edit form that contain data only.  For example, if fields have not been completed in the new request form, hide these from view and only display those that have a value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The simples way is to add script webpart (content webpart or script webpart depends on sharepoint version) on the edit form. And then write some simple javascript code to hide fields if empty